# Can you debug go with delve in Eclipse Che

Tags: eclipse-che, delve

Can anybody help with directions on how to debug go in eclipse che with delve?

Note: I am running che in docker container.

Thanks
Regards

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with Go, but Delve looks like it's executed from the command line so you can add it to your stack and it's ready to go. For more about customizing stacks see the docs: http://www.eclipse.org/che/docs/devops/runtime-stacks/index.html